# Django: I cant create a model, I got this error:[pylint] E0001:invalid syntax (<string>, line 8)

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, python-3.5

> file: models.py

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.db import models

class Register(models.Model):
    name =models.Charfield(max_length = 100,blank=True,null=True)
    email =models.EmailField()
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,auto_now=False)

    def__unicode__(self):
        return self.mail

    def__str__(self): 
        return self.mail
```

> Details:

- error: [pylint] E0001:invalid syntax (, line 8)  in word: class
- I try to execute command-line: 
  **python manage.py makemigrations**
- message is: No changes detected.
- I use python 3.7,sqllite,Django 2.0.1

Comment: check your indentation(maybe your indentation is messed up by mixing spaces and tabs, try converting the whole indentation to tabs/spaces) and remove any syntax errors (in your case, you missed a colon)..

Comment: @zaidfazil please don't edit questions in such a way as to remove the syntax error that OP was asking about.

Comment: Sorry about that. Thought it was just a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing spaces after `def`.

```
def __unicode__(self):
    return self.mail

def __str__(self): 
    return self.mail
```

Note, you should not be defining `__unicode__` at all, it is not used in Python 3.

Comment: yes, it's ok.. thanks i have a lot of errors because change my editor :)